# "Move/Copy/Promote" feature in Jenkins is not showing the desired folder as an option

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, cloudbees

I have an `OI folder` existing under the `VCPS Controller.`

But unable to move a job into the `OI folder.`

[image]

However, the "Move/Copy/Promote" is not showing the OI folder when trying to move job into the OI folder.

[image]